# Multi Output Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: python, architecture, conv-neural-network

I am developing a convolutional neural network for image classification or better for classification of license plates. These license plates contain up to 8 characters and for each character 37 characters are possible (A-Z, 0-9 and a blank space). I am now wondering how to design the two last layers in my network. I think, the last one has to be a softmax layer with 37 probabilities. This should be fully connected to one(?) neuron in the layer before? I think, in the layer before we need 8 neurons because of the 8 characters in the license plate before but I am not sure here.
Before this layers I add some convolutional and maxPooling layers. Is that a valid approach or do you have other suggestions?

I wrote this code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape = (600, 1200, 1), activation = "relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dense(8, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dense(37, activation = "softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Especially regarding the layers after my Flatten Layer I am really unsure... Is there someone who can help? I hope I described my problem properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your previous layers, there are many commonly used architectures which you could try to obtain better accuracy on your dataset.

On the dense layers, there are multiple ways you could tackle it.
Since, there are atmost 8 characters with 37 possible characters each. You could have the last layer as `model.add(Dense(37*8, activation = "sigmoid"))` with thresholding at 0.5 to denote all the 37*8 possibilities.

```
 model = Sequential()
 model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape = (600, 1200, 1), activation = "relu"))
 model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
 model.add(Dropout(0.25))
 model.add(Flatten())
 model.add(Dense(64, activation = "relu"))
 model.add(Dense(37*8, activation = "relu"))
```

A more apt way could be having 9 output layers: one with 8 neurons to denote the the presence of a character and other 8 layers with 37 neurons each with softmax to denote what character it is. Note that to do this you must use Functional API instead of Sequential API.

An example:

```
 inp = Input(shape=(600,1200,1))
 X = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation = "relu")(inp)
 X = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(X)
 X = Dropout(0.25)(X)
 X = Flatten()(X)
 X = Dense(64, activation = "relu")(X)
 P = Dense(8, activation = "relu")(X)
 C1 = Dense(37, activation = "softmax")(X)
 ...
 C8 = Dense(37, activation = "softmax")(X)
 model = Model(inp, [P,C1,C2,...C8])
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much! That sounds interesting to me! Nevertheless, I am still a little struggling with the code, especially the below one. I tried to apply it to my data and got the following error code: `ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 9 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[[0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],`. I am especially wondering because it says it wants to see 9 input arrays. I have 8 arrays of 37 characters, what ninth array is wanted?

Comment: One addtional question: when I use the first code for the sequential API. I need to have a target of shape (1, 296) instead of (8, 37). Does this make sense?